# Setting up VLAN

Tags: vlan, networking

One of our clients has an intranet connection and they are reluctant to use internet for our needs (data collection). They have 4 buildings.

1) Admin

2) Canteen

3) EM

4) Mill

The configuration which I am planning to do is as follows.

Router -> Switches -> Sub switches -- Data logger (Schneider EBX) With the help of VLAN, I can logically connect them for the 4 buildings. I have not yet decided on the switches and other network devices.

I need to set up VLAN for all the 4 buildings. My question is

1) Since the client has intranet how should I use their router to set up the VLAN? (Does intranet use router?)

2) Can you give some example on the approach since they are using intranet and they are concerned about cyber security issues?

Any advice would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Welcome! You will need to provide a lot more details if you want people to help you. For example, you will need to provide a network diagram, configurations and a more detailed description what you mean by 'has intranet'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An intranet would not need a router unless the intranet was subnetted. A router is used to route traffic between different networks and an intranet is technicaly one network, although it can be subnetted into different networks within itself. The VLAN would be configured on switches not the router.

Comment: Thanks Andy. Can you explain the flow? From Intranet to Main Switches followed by subset of switches and followed by devices.

Comment: The intranet is basically an internal network so is designed the same as any other network but without an option to send data/ communicate outside of that intranet. The flow from the intranet to main switches ( I am presuming you are refering to switches outside the inranet) would be directed through a router. Devices on the inranet would have to be configured with a default gateway ( which is the routers ip address) The router should be configured as router on a stick configuration if the intranet is divided into various VLAN's.

Comment: The router would direct traffic to the appropriate switches which inturn direct to the approriate hosts.

Comment: Hope this helps